# Android CursorLoader not responding to ContentProvider notifications

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I'm updating an Android 2.2 application to use CursorLoader (using the v4 compatibility library) and I'm tearing my hair out trying to understand why the `onLoadFinished` method is not called when the content provider notifies a change in the content associated with the CursorLoader query.

The CursorLoader is querying a customer content provider. My provider sets the notification URI in its query method:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

and notifies changes in its insert/update/delete methods:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

I've checked that the URI is identical in both cases. Previously I was using a ManagedQuery with the same content provider and queried content was updated fine, which makes me think the content provider is probably ok.

I've looked at the [LoaderCursorSupport](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/LoaderCursorSupport.html) example and, interestingly, when I run it on my Nexus One I don't see it reflect changes I make to contact names (switching between the example app and the contacts app). Should it? If so, is there some underlying problem I'm not aware of?

Comment: could you provide some code to help us pin-point the problem?

Comment: Enabling debugging might help, `LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging(true)`

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip. My client code is essentially the same as the LoaderCursorSupport example I referenced. Given that this exhibits the same problem, have I misunderstood how CursorLoader is supposed to work i.e. if I run the support example to show a list of contacts, then edit the contact in the address book, should it not change in the list displayed by the example app?

Comment: I'm not managing a cursor. I'm creating a Loader<Cursor> in onCreateLoader as per the example. What's initLoader()?

Comment: so let me understand this correctly... are you making changes to the data currently being displayed (i.e. you change the name of a contact being displayed), or do you want to display a different set of data (i.e. you want to perform another query and display that data instead?)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I appreciate your efforts to help me with this. To clarify, I'm making changes to the data currently being displayed. In the context of the LoaderCursorSupport example, I pick a contact in the list it displays, modify the name in the contacts app, and switch back to the example app. If I've understood correctly, the CursorLoader should have registered for notifications and the onLoadFinished() method should be called after a notification has triggered a requery.

Comment: sorry, i really can't tell what is wrong... the only information you've given me is that you followed the example given on the Android developers site... but that leads me to believe that it should be working perfectly fine. are you able to post some of your code?

Answer (score 4):

I finally got to the bottom of this and, as is usually the way, it was a stupid mistake on my part. I was calling cursor.close() in my onLoadFinished() method - I use the returned cursor to create an ArrayAdapter (I need to manually insert an item at the top of the list) and the cursor close was a leftover from using a ManagedQuery before migrating to use CursorLoader.

In the process of finding this, I created a simple test class to display a list of bookmarks and add a random bookmark (using the options menu). This worked as it should i.e. onLoadFinished() is called after the item is added. Here's the code in case it's useful for anyone else:

```
package com.test;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class CursorLoaderTestActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
    private static final String TAG = CursorLoaderTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) 
        {
            CursorLoaderListFragment list = new CursorLoaderListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
    }


    public static class CursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> 
    {

        // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

        // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
        String mCurFilter;

        @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
            // application this would come from a resource.
            setEmptyText("No data");

            // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
            mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                    new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE },
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);

            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            // Start out with a progress indicator.
            setListShown(false);

            // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
            // or start a new one.
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        //@Override 
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
        {
            // Place an action bar item for searching.
            MenuItem item = menu.add("Add Item");
            //item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
            MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
        {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, "!AA " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            cv.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, "http://test/");
            cv.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
            getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, cv);
            return true;
        }

       //columns to query
        static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE };


        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader");

            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    PROJECTION, null, null,
                    Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE + " ASC");
        }

        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished");

            // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
            // old cursor once we return.)
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

            // The list should now be shown.
            if (isResumed()) 
                setListShown(true);
            else 
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }

        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) 
        {
            // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
            // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
            // longer using it.
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Cursor should be kept alive until another is supplied in onLoadFinished().

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use application context:

```
getContext().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

Comment: This didn't make any difference I'm afraid.